# Can erule produce erroneous subgoals?

Tags: isabelle, proof

I have the following grammar defined in Isabelle:

```
inductive S where
  S_empty: "S []" |
  S_append: "S xs ⟹ S ys ⟹ S (xs @ ys)" |
  S_paren: "S xs ⟹ S (Open # xs @ [Close])"
```

Then I define a gramar T that conceptually only adds the following rule:

```
  T_left: "T xs ⟹ T (Open # xs)"
```

Then I tried to proof the following theorem:

```
theorem T_S:
  "T xs ⟹ count xs Open = count xs Close ⟹ S xs"
  apply(erule T.induct)
  apply(simp add: S_empty)
  apply(simp add: S_append)
  apply(simp add: S_paren)
  oops
```

To my surprise the final goal seems to be false:

```
⋀xsa. count xs Open = count xs Close ⟹ T xsa ⟹ S xsa ⟹ S (Open # xsa)
```

So here `S (Open # xsa)` cannot hold because there is no such production in the grammar assuming `S xsa`.

This situation makes no-sense to me? Is erule producing goals that are false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction rules like `T.induct` should usually be used with the `induction` proof method rather than `erule`. The `induction` method ensures that the whole statement becomes part of the inductive statements whereas with `erule` only the conclusion is part of the inductive argument; other assumptions are basically ignored for the induction. This can be seen in the last goal state where the inductive statement involves the goal parameter `xsa` whereas the crucial assumption `count xs Open = count xs Close` still talks about the variable `xs`. So, the proof step should be `apply(induction rule: T.induct)`. Then there is a chance to prove this statement.